# How to dual OS 32-bit/64-bit Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, operating-systems, 32-bit, multi-boot

I have a problem with regards to my nVidia driver not running on 64-bit.
I decided to install both 32-bit and 64-bit on my ASUS K42JC (4GB RAM upgrade) in order to function the nVidia on the 32-bit.

My question is, how could I make my laptop run on either 32-bit or 64-bit OS.
What options I am suppose to use, a single, double, or triple partition?

From an answer:

Well. When I installed the nVidia driver from either the ASUS site and the prescribed driver from NVIDA site via System Requirements Lab, both ended up freezing my laptop to the point when the desktop is about the finish booting.

I have tried three(3) times reformatting and trying to fix the problem. Yet no use.
I filed a ticket to the Asus support but for now no replies yet.

But this bothers me, why wouldn't the nVidia run on 64bit yet it runs perfectly on 32bit.

Comment: What problems are you having with the nVidia graphics card in 64-bit Windows? I use nVidia graphics cards all the time and have had no problems using them on 64-bit installations. Fixing that seems like it would be far easier and better than dual-booting.

Comment: What graphics card does your system have? I have an nVidia card in 64-bit Windows 7 with no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dual booting windows is really easy. Just make a double partition, and install both versions of Windows. The Windows installer should be able to correctly modify the bootloader to allow booting into both versions

But, did you check for 64bit version on the drive you are looking for on the nVidia website?